# Graphire CTE-640 pad wheel stops working after a minute

Tags: wacom

I have a Wacom CTE-640; it used to work fine before, only after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 that I found that the scroll wheel and the buttons on the pad does not work. However, I have also observed that immediately after plugging in the device the wheel works for a minute or so, and then it again stops working. Please can you help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug in the xorg driver. You should report the bug here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Then to help gather the information, you should add the relevant parts of your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file so we can see what is happening. you may also wish to add the data here in your question as well as the bug report so others with the same issue can check.

also worth trying is the 11.10 Beta, you might find the issue is fixed. Don't forget that these wacom tablets will work from the live cd, so you can try it out without installing.